# Android: How store url in string.xml resource file?

Tags: android, xml, string, url

I'm trying to store a fully qualified url, with also query params:

```
www.miosito.net?prova&reg=bis
```

but it's causing a problem because `&reg` is similar to `&reg;` entity and android tell me that and html entity is not well written.

I need this because every locale uses a fully different set of url query param.

I tried with `[[CDATA[.. ]]` but this syntax disliked by xml parser.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is not with `&req` but with `&` itself. For XML/HTML you would have to use `&amp;` entity (or `&#38;`), but for URLs you should rather URL-encode ([see docs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)) strings, and in that case said `&` should be replaced with `%26`. So your final string should look like:

> www.miosito.net?prova%26reg=bis

Answer (score 6):

Store it like this:

```
<string name="my_url">"www.miosito.net?prova&amp;reg=bis"</string>
```

Where `&amp;` is the XML equivelant of the *ampersand symbol* `&`.

Answer (score 1):

Percent encoding may do the trick: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding
You'll basically have something like this: www.miosito.net?prova%26reg=bis

Answer (score 1):

You can enclose your url in double quotes, something like :

```
<string name="my_url">"www.miosito.net?prova&reg=bis"</string>
```

This is a recommended way to enclose string resources in Android.

Update 1 : Have a look at the following link for more info :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling

Update 2:
@WebnetMobile.com : Correct, indeed :) 
'&' is being treated a special character by xml and enclosing in quotes doesn't work. I tried out  
    `www.miosito.net?prova%26reg=bis`

and it didn't work out either. I even tried enclosing it in quotes but still didn't work. Am I missing something ? 
 
Meanwhile, the following does work : 
 
    `<string name="my_url">www.miosito.net%1$sprova%2$sreg=bis</string>` 
 
and then in code : 
 
    `Resources resources=getResources();` 
    `String url=String.format(resources.getString(R.string.my_url),"?","&") ;`

The '%1$s' and '%2$s' are format specifiers, much like what is used in printf in C. '%1$s' is for strings, '%2$d' is for decimal numbers and so on.

Comment: it will not work: "The reference to entity "reg" must end with the ';' delimiter.";