# Storing URLs in string.xml resource file?

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm trying to place some API URLs somewhere so that the app can fetch them when needed. For instance, it needs to fetch the Google Calendar API URLs to retrieve the calendars, events, etc.

Is it a good idea to have them hardcoded and stored in string.xml? Otherwise, what would be a better approach?

Thanks

Comment: You should store it in Constant file of your program. Store url in xml file is not proper way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237462/android-how-store-url-in-string-xml-resource-file) you can store url in string.xml

I personnaly prefer to create a "contract" file in order to store informations about API. For example

```
//No need to use "static final" attributes because this is an interface an not a class
public interface APIContract {
    String BASE_URL = "";
    //...
}
```

Now you can use it in your code using

```
APIContract.BASE_URL
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend storing all URL's in a Constants.java file

Comment: I agree since Google Calendar API URL would not need to change based on locale there's no advantage to storing it in the resources.  Plus you would need to escape the character "&" if storing in xml. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237462/android-how-store-url-in-string-xml-resource-file

Comment: @Vaibhav, You should give your suggestion in comment instead of post ans.

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose between string resource and constants  , here some pro. and con.

Localization:

For localization issue definitely String resource is the best as you can use different language file for different Locale.

Memory:

As String resources are saved in xml file so there are some extra overhead (not a major one though)

Performance:

reading from memory is always faster than reading from file. Although in this case the performance difference is not significant

I personally use constant classes since i need no translation between languages for the Urls , better performance .