# How to redirect page for unauthorized user

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I having a asp.net program that i can only configure with web.config file.
Having this code below, it could help me redirect to login page.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="ZukamiLogin" path="/" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
 <deny users="?" />
```

However, when i changed the loginUrl to "login.aspx?AppID=90441b68-3515-4fdd-851a-4a2b753e5557&anonyform=2f7fbed9-3ef4-4e9d-b164-0f4b6104cf78" , it shows me error. Is there any way to redirect user to this link instead of login.aspx?

Edit : 
added with image for the error
[image]

Comment: What's the error it shows you?

Comment: @RobertM. HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Comment: Does the URL you want to use work in the browser when you try to navigate to it directly?

Comment: @davke yes, that's why it make me clueless

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, could you click it as accepted please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have special characters ?, =, or . in tags or attributes because they are special characters in XML. You have to use their numeric character reference.

So:

```
loginUrl="login.aspx&#63;AppID&#6190441b68&#45;3515&#45;4fdd&#45;851a&#45;4a2b753e5557&#38;anonyform&#612f7fbed9&#45;3ef4&#45;4e9d&#45;b164&#45;0f4b6104cf78"
```

(you might want to check my typing)

This has the whole table of character references: https://www.dvteclipse.com/documentation/svlinter/How_to_use_special_characters_in_XML.3F.html#gsc.tab=0

Edit:
Apparently for URLs it's better to use a different character encoding scheme (URL-encode) explained in the accepted answer here: [Android: How store url in string.xml resource file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237462/android-how-store-url-in-string-xml-resource-file)

Comment: it is working, thx Robert! 
P/S : Friendly reminder to all potential reader. 
Replace "&" first before replace other special character if using "replace all" function in notepad ++

Comment: Even better: use this tool to do URL-encoding in one click.