# Is is possible to save url in values/strings and then access it when using retrofit in Android Studio?

Tags: android, string, retrofit

I what to put everything related with urls that connect to the server in values/string, Is that possible? Here is what I have:

```
     private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://www.url.com")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(client)
    .build()
```

Can I save the https://www.url.com in the folder res/values/Strings? Like this?

```
     <string name="https://www.url.com">https://www.url.com"</string>
```

I'm just not sure how to access it if I do this.
If this is not possible is there anyway to put anything related to server/url in another class?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You will need a `Context` object to retrieve that string.

```
class ApiFactory(private val appContext: Context) {
    ...
    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(context.getString(R.string.your_url))
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build()
    ...
}
```

**Note:** Do not pass an Activity context here which may cause issues. Read [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html). Pass the Application Context as mentioned in the link

Answer (score 0):

You can create empty kotlin file and add public constants over there.

Constants file :

```
const val MY_BASE_URL = "https://www.url.com"
const val MY_ENDPOINT = "/names"
```

Or you can create a class and add everything inside companion object.

Constants.kt :

```
class Constants {

    companion object {
        const val MY_BASE_URL = "https://www.url.com"
        const val MY_ENDPOINT = "/names"
    }
}
```

You can access them both ways.
You still wish to add those to your `strings.xml` ?

Imagine have to use string url from `strings.xml` :

If `Activity` `Fragment` or any class which has context : You have access to context to call a string.

```
getContext(getString(R.string.url))
getString(getString(R.string.url))
```

But you won't have access to it when the class cannot have it's own context.

You should also read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237462/android-how-store-url-in-string-xml-resource-file).

Comment: I just throught of the strings.xml because it was the only that made more sence to me. But I'm going to try with the constants and if that works I'll just use that

Comment: I never wanted to do it. Since url's have slashes and so many symbols, I feel not so good while I see it. And the thing about saving in string.xml is you cannot access it without calling Context or Reference, I mean getString( ), getResources.getString( ), getContext.getString( ). If I have class for strings or any values then all I need is to import a statement.

Comment: Creating a Constants file doesn't seam to be working. I'm going to try using with string

Comment: Oh, can you post what you have tried? I'm pretty sure it will work perfectly.

Comment: I did exactly like you said, and when I check de server nothing's there. Do you think that maybe its because my endpoint is "ocorrenciasapi" and instead of "/ocorrenciasapi". However my server url ends with /. Can that couse some issues?

Comment: It is a good idea to print your url in logs first, and see if the response is right.

Comment: It works fine if I implement the url and the endpoint in their places it works fine, so the problem it's not in the url

Comment: Okay I understood. If you want to try once again, check if the appending path, segments and query parameters of your url and endpoints are done correctly.